# XAMPP Error Solution? I have that installed on my Windows XP Dual Boot Machine

Tags: php, windows, installation, xampp, uac

My system is dual boot, **Win-XP Professional (32-bit) an Win-7 (64-bit)**.
I have XAMPP installed on my XP OS (**C:/XAMPP**).

I want to use the same htdocs directory for testing the php on my windows also.
But when I am installing the XAMPP on the same directory, I am getting this error.

> Important! Because an activated User Account Control (UAC) on your
>   sytem some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted. With UAC please
>   avoid to install XAMPP to C:\Program Files (x86) (missing write
>   permisssions). Or deactivate UAC with msconfig after this setup.

Can someone please help me in resolving this thing?

Thanks.

[image: XAMPP Error Solution? I have that installed on my Windows XP Dual Boot Machinee]

Comment: Do you have all the administrator privileges in win7? The error sounds like it's related with it.

Comment: yes, i am the only administrator for both operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : open Start Menu -> Run.. and type "lusrmgr.msc" inside. In the opened window, click "Users" on the left menu, then double-click on your username in the middle and then select "Member Of" in the opened window. Do you see "Administrators" there?

BTW you can try installing XAMPP in another directory, then open php.ini and set the VirtualDirectory parameters to point your previous XAMPP htdocs folder.

Comment: try running "Control userpasswords2" in Start Menu -> Run and then doubleclick to your username, and in "Group Membership" select Administrators if it isn't selected. What happens then?

Comment: THanks. I have completed this step. Now what should I do? How shall I install and use htdocs of XP ?

Comment: ok you have an existing installation on C:\XAMPP right? And you've installed it on your WinXP machine. Hmm. Lets try this once, Right click on your xampp setup file and run as administrator, then select repair if exists in there. See what happens if you do install like this.

Comment: While running as administrator in installing the setup, it is showing the same message as I have shown in my question's screenshot. Shall I try your method of changing directory in php.ini ?

Comment: you should install a new XAMPP somewhere else and edit its php.ini file to point at the first one's folder. otherwise you'd mess with the XP installation.

Comment: I installed XAMPP in C:/7xampp but in C:/7xampp/php/php.ini , I am unable to find the option VirtualDirectory in php.ini file.

Comment: ok sorry, my bad, the file is C:\7xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf. edit the Vhost url's at the end of the file. and restart apache.

Comment: I changed that to following, and restarted the apache, mysql. but they are picking from same new installation.

    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"

Comment: there are some other configuration settings in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf like DocumentRoot, <Directory> etc. Change them too.

Comment: only these lines are written twice. and nothing else 

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

Comment: no no no.. the lines starting with # are comments. they are not effective. At the bottom there you should see a c:\xampp\htdocs. and dont forget to change the other file I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. I changed everything, and it worked. But now one thing is missing, that the mysql databases are not in phpmyadmin. Can i use them here as well. So that if I add some data in those databases from here, then it will also change in my XP's XAMPP.

Comment: It came thanks, by changing datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data" in my.ini
but now I see that phpmyadmin is showing error when i click on databases. Error : #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_tracking' doesn't exist

Comment: try heidisql for mysql. it's better imho.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough for a clear answer - but it sounds like you are trying to install XAMPP on your Windows 7 OS but use XP's htdocs folder as the content?

The warning you are receiving is from Windows 7 UAC, which authenticates all of your actions etc. when enabled.  Go to your accounts and disable UAC, then you should be able to install XAMPP without this error message.  However, if you are trying to install it in the same location then it will likely overwrite your XP installation.  The question is very vague.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You're right. But then Will I be able to use the same htdocs folder in windows XP again. I often use XP and sometimes use win 7.

Comment: I want like, if I enter http://localhost on both of my OS,
then they open pages from same htdocs folder.