# Change the default install folder in NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, windows-7-x64

I'm writing a installer for windows using nsis. This installer contains a web application which is run on top of xampp, so xampp is also installed as a service with this application. But xamp gives an issue when it installed in 64bit machine on Windows 7. This is due to the directory path issue in C:\Program Files (x86) as mentioned here.

[XAMPP Error Solution? I have that installed on my Windows XP Dual Boot Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771928/xampp-error-solution-i-have-that-installed-on-my-windows-xp-dual-boot-machine)

But currently the automatic installation path is set as follows in the installer.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\myapplication
```

The installer script just have the following macro to add the directory chooser page.

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

As a solution what I'm going to do are following actions.

1. Change the default directory to c:\Program Files
2. If the user choose the x86 folder give an error message to choose another directory.

For that I need to get the install directory path by

```
$INSTDIR
```

and

1. check whether there is a sub string of x86 with that path
2. if so give the error messages.
3. Change the default path to c:\Program Files

Since I'm not much familiar with nsis I'm unable to write this program.

Can someone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a win7/64, the 64 bits program files can be get from a 32 bit application via the `%ProgramW6432%` environment variable.

You could try to get it with `ReadEnvStr` :

- on a 32bit system it will return an empty string
- on a 64 bit system it will return `c:\program files` (if not configured elsewhere)

Here is a snippet that test it :

```
ReadEnvStr $0 ProgramW6432
StrCmp $0 "" 0 +3
MessageBox MB_OK "it is a 32b system"
goto +2
MessageBox MB_OK "it is a 64b system"
```

In your case, it could do :

```
ReadEnvStr $0 ProgramW6432
StrCmp $0 "" +2 0
StrCpy $INSTDIR $0
```

**Edit**: For the point to refuse `Program Files (x86)` you could use the `.onVerifyInstDir` callback method that was given by Anders for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955529/317266), it will check the choosen directory as it is selected by the user and before changing the page :

```
Function .onVerifyInstDir
  ReadEnvStr $0 "ProgramFiles(x86)"
  StrCmp $0 $INSTDIR 0 PathGood
  MessageBox MB_OK "directory not valid for installation"
  Abort
PathGood:
FunctionEnd
```

Here, I use another environment variable to get the (x86) variant of program files.

Comment: This is great and works with the default path scenario. But what if the user change the directory to "C:\Program Files (x86)" manually. This will not solve the problem at that time. Can you specify a solution for that instance also.

Comment: sorry, I must have read your question too quickly. You would like to make a check after the user has selected the directory to refuse any folder that contains "(x86)" ? If yes, I think I have a solution and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

NSIS provides $PROGRAMFILES32 and $PROGRAMFILES64:

```
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\myapp"
```

Comment: Thanks Anders and Seki was following one of your previous answers.

Comment: If using CPACK this variable is set as:  SET(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALL_ROOT "$PROGRAMFILES64")